# What format is optimal for storing data from rich text editor

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, rich-text-editor

I'm building component which allows user to write rich text post. Now I'm facing the dilemma: what format should I choose for serializing.

With some editors I can transform data to HTML, JSON, md and generally speaking any format I want. If this data would be used only by my React app there would be no question, but in the future data from server will be shipped to many apps, including mobile.

So the question is which format will be easy to reuse on any platform

Comment: I would use HTML, even because as it's a string only representing the structure of information and the style layout, you can also have different CSS for every place where you show it in case you want this, and it's already in a standard format that is understood by many platforms.

Comment: which format do you get from the editor? what happens after editing with the data?

Comment: Most editors have JSON representation data. But I can serialize and deserialize the way I want.

Comment: @TelmoDias Yeah, I prefer HTML to, but isn't for example markdown is more light and easy to reuse? And JSON I think is like more declarative: I have data and no info how to represent it, so it is up to app and more customizable

Comment: @KostyaTresko at the end of the day, many factors can influence your decision. But if you're talking about rich text information, I would say there is a reason why the Internet is based on HTML and CSS and not on other formats. But I guess it really depends on how you intend to process and use this information and what other benefits would you get from storing in another format.

Comment: @TelmoDias yeah, it's very top level and tough decidion